# What are these very small angular holes in clusters on my ground?

Tags: identification, pests

This spring I've noticed a bunch of holes almost everywhere on my property which is located in Doboj, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Europe. N44.73, E18.08.

The holes are forming some kind of clusters, from 2 up to 10 holes. The diameter of the holes is about 2 - 3 cm (.75 - 1 in), and most of them are angled, not vertical. Unfortunately I forgot to check how deep they are.

What could make these holes and how should I treat them if they are made by some animal (pest)?

[image: holes 1]
[image: holes 2]
[image: holes 3]

Comment: Do you have birds such as [jays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay) around your garden, and an oak tree nearby? Have you opened up a hole to see what's inside?

Comment: @AndrewMorton We have just one oak tree on property which is prety far from those holes (but there many other oak trees around as we are surrounded by forest). We also have all sorts of birds visiting garden/orchard in including jays and common blackbirds, woodpeckers etc. I'll try to dig up one hole next time I get there.

Comment: I think we need to know where in the world you are. For a UK answer I might say solitary bees  It is unusual to see so many together but it could be. The UK gets lots of burrowing insects and beatles, most of which are harmless or beneficial to a garden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My boyfriend says these are holes made by [crickets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_(insect)) and he has seen this type of holes on hills outside his native town. The holes may be 20 or 30 cm deep. He also swears it is not an April 1st joke.

Comment: I think your boyfriend was right about crickets. When I was tilling ground there were crickets showing all over the place and I also found some white grubs (I'll upload pictures to my question).

Answer (score 5):

The Holes are probably made by the cicada nymphs. Nymphs stays below the dirt, digging, and eating tree roots for years. when they are mature enough, they dig out of the ground, climb the nearest tree and molt into adults. [image]

Comment: What kind of damage adult insects do?

Comment: I dont really know. The adults doesn't do anything except making loud noises and annoying people nearby. The nymphs feed on tree roots, but they are too small to cause harm.

Answer (score 1):

Since we cannot fully inspect your area, it's probably best to call a pest control company. Almost any hole that is angled is going to be a creature of some kind. These look like insect  holes to me, as well. A pest company will be able to get rid of them safely and precisely without causing unintended collateral damage to your property and other plants. If they are crickets, you will have a heck of a time trying to eradicate then yourself. Crickets are proliferous, persistent, and good at hiding. So, good luck.

Comment: But, healthy soil have rich insect life - is there any particular reason to eradicate them?

Comment: Good point. She just mentioned "how to treat them". So I wanted to encourage a professional, if so. If the holes are close to the house, and it is crickets, they will come inside and breed and make noise night and day. Lots of"ifs" though. I just generally try to discourage people from Willy-nilly treating pests without more expert advice.